Error: Response is not an ArrayBuffer | unable to make api requests of responseType 'arraybuffer'
I'm getting this console error when trying to make a api request to download a pdf file.
service.ts
public getFileContent(fileURL: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(fileURL, { responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
        .pipe(
            catchError(error => this.responseHandler.error(error, 'Error retrieving file content.'))
        );
}

component.ts
this.fileDownloadService
        .getFileContent(this.fileDetails.fileUid)
        .subscribe((res) => {
            const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            this.fileURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
                window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            );
        });


I have tried changing the responseType to 'blob' then I get this error 'Error: Response is not a Blob.'
any help would be highly appreciated. thank you.
this is the error message btw

and api response in swagger is:


the backend is serving a file.  Just let the browser get the response by creating a standard link to the URL and setting target="_blank".  Ex: Link to File  Target may or may not be necessary... you can also target an invisible iframe if it suits your needs.  (creating an ObjectURL slows things down a little as it will create a copy and use up some client-side storage)

I ended up using fetch API to get the file with blob response type. Not sure why it didn't work with HttpClient.
fetch(fileURL).then(res => {
  const blob = await res.blob();
  this.iframeSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});


Try removing the response type, so that the error goes away.
public getFileContent(fileURL: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(fileURL)
        .pipe(
            catchError(error => this.responseHandler.error(error, 'Error retrieving file content.'))
        );
}

Then directly use this response. Would suggest you do a console.log check the return type using typeof and proceed from there, but the actual solution is to change the API to return blob, so that your work becomes easier
this.fileDownloadService
        .getFileContent(this.fileDetails.fileUid)
             .subscribe(image => { 
                  console.log(image, typeof image);
                  const blob = new Blob([image], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                  this.fileURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
                      window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                  );
             })


@Luther try now?

Thanks for answering.  If I don't explicitly mention responseType in get request (as you have suggested in the above code) default response type json is considered and it results in a parse error. This is the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%', "%PDF-1.7 "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse..."

@Luther Try response type as 'text'

with responseType='text' it returns file contents as a string in the reponse body but I'm unable to convert that into blob. Here's a screenshot of the error https://imgur.com/a/fnyIrCb

@Luther There is no error in the screenshot, try const blob = new Blob([image.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });

my apologies, thats a log of the api response in the screenshot. I've tried passing image.body to  the Blob() but the fileURL renders a blank pdf (I've binded the fileURL variable to an iframe).
